# problem redirecting stdout of C functions when imported in python

Tags: python, c, swig, python-c-extension

I wrote a simple C module which prints to stdout using printf.

```
// sample.c
func_print()
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

Later, I made a wrapper around this using `SWIG` so that I could use `func_print` in my python program too. In this program, I have redirected the stdout to a textctrl widget. Anything I print using `print` prints correctly in the textctrl widget, as expected.

```
# sample.py
...
sys.stdout = textctrl          # textctrl is a TextCtrl widget (wxPython).
print 'Hello from Python!'     # prints in the textctrl widget, as expected.
```

However, when I call the C function `func_print()` (from sample.py), it prints to the terminal instead of the textctrl widget.

```
func_print()                   # [Problem] prints to the terminal window, instead of the textctrl widget.
```

Somehow, it seems that the `stdout` for functions in the C module do not get redirected as expected. Please help me fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that `sys.stdout` is a Python object, not an actual C stream or file descriptor.  From the [sys.stdout documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdout):

> (Changing these objects doesn’t affect the standard I/O streams of
>   processes executed by os.popen(), os.system() or the exec*() family of
>   functions in the os module.)

Your C code is not unlike a process spawned by `os.system`, in that it only has access to traditional Unix file descriptors for output, not Python objects.  (Well, not without some extra work, anyway.)

If you just want to redirect stdout at the system level to another file or socket, see [os.dup2](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.dup2).

But if you really want to send output to a Python object from C, see [Calling Python Functions From C](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#calling-python-functions-from-c).